# Manipulate/Lookup Markup from Code

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

we have some generalised functionality in our programs for UserControls. Unfortunatelly, I need to exclude some elements from the processing, depending on whether a certain attribute (i.e. IsReadOnly) was set explicitly in markup.

I think the easiest way is to take a look at the XAML that was used to declare the element. How can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

If you add your generalized functionality as [attached behaviours](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/AttachedBehaviors.aspx), you can enable/disable them via DataTriggers in your Styles